# Deep copy of entity and relationships using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, deep-copy

I have three tables

```
Store
  Book
    Page
```

A store is one-to-many to books, book is one-to-many to pages and they all have the foreign keys set. I want to create copies of the store (and consequently, the books and pages) using a SQL query. I've tried using CTE's, but I'm having trouble maintaining the relationships between the entities.

I'm not trying to create a new table, just creating a duplicate of a specific Store row (and its relationships), the ids on the tables are serial.

So a copy of

```
Store 1
  Book 1 (store_id: 1)
    Page 1 (book_id: 1)
    Page 2 (book_id: 1)
```

Would be

```
Store 2
  Book 2 (store_id: 2)
    Page 3 (book_id: 2)
    Page 4 (book_id: 2)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Are you trying to create a new table?  Or just adding rows into existing tables?  Do you want to copy all stores?  Or just one store?  Are the ids in the tables serial columns?

Comment: @GordonLinoff you're right, added missing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that Postgres will preserve ordering of the serial ids when an `insert . . . select` has an `order by`.  So, you can do what you want by using `returning` and creating a mapping table from the old and the new values:

```
with s as (
      insert into stores ( . . . )
          select . . .
          from stores
          where store_id = @x
          returning *
     ),
     b as (
      insert into books (store_id, . . . )
          select s.store_id, . . .
          from books b cross join
               s
          where b.store_id = @x
          order by b.book_id
          returning *
     ),
     bb as (
      select bold.book_id as old_book_id, bnew.book_id as new_book_id
      from (select b.book_id,
                   row_number() over (order by book_id) as seqnum
            from books b cross join
                 s
            where b.store_id = @x
           ) bold join
           (select b.*, row_number() over (order by book_id) as seqnum
            from b
           ) bnew
           on bnew.seqnum = bold.seqnum
      )
insert into pages (book_id, . . .)
    select bb.new_book_id, . . .
    from pages p join
         bb b
         on p.book_id = bb.old_book_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works perfectly for the example I gave. But imagine that the page entity also had a child relationship, let's call it "Words" for the sake of the argument. Since the mapping is dependent on the store_id, how would it work?

My real problem has a hierarchy of 6 entities, so I was trying to find a way to always access the old_id of a child's parent entity, but I can't seem to find a way to do it, maybe I'm not going the right way about it.

Comment: @DiogoMartins . . . The simplest method is if you happen to have other columns that uniquely identify each row.  Of course after this operation, that won't be true any more.